# UICollectionView performBatchUpdates: animates all sections

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm writing a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and I've noticed that `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` and `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` will be called for all sections when I invoke `performBatchUpdates:completion:` on the collection view. The result is that *all* sections have the animation applied to them instead of *just* the newly added section.

```
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    currentModelArrayIndex++;
    [collectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentModelArrayIndex]];
    [collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentModelArrayIndex-1]];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:currentModelArrayIndex] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}];
```

What I've tried so far is removing the call to `performBatchUpdates:completion:` in lieu of simple updates, but the already existing sections (all of them) are animated in anyway. I've come up with a solution of checking to make sure that I'm changing the layout attributes of *only* the last section, but it feels hacky.

```
if (decorationIndexPath.section == [(id<UICollectionViewDataSource>)self.collectionView.delegate numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:self.collectionView] - 1)
{
   layoutAttributes.alpha = 0.0f;
   layoutAttributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-CGRectGetWidth(layoutAttributes.frame), 0, 0);
}
```

Is this the proper way to go about animating only some sections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I've got an answer; it's not a lot prettier than the previous one, but it keeps the layout from touching the datasource, so it's cleaner.

Basically, we need to override `prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:` and `finalizeCollectionViewUpdates` to keep track of the sections that we're inserting. I have a mutable set that contains `NSNumber` instances of the sections that we're inserting.

```
-(void)prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:(NSArray *)updateItems
{
    [super prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:updateItems];

    [updateItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UICollectionViewUpdateItem *updateItem, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (updateItem.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateActionInsert)
        {
            [insertedSectionSet addObject:@(updateItem.indexPathAfterUpdate.section)];
        }
    }];
}

-(void)finalizeCollectionViewUpdates
{
    [super finalizeCollectionViewUpdates];

    [insertedSectionSet removeAllObjects];
}
```

Next, I check to see if the index path's section is included in that set when setting the initial layout attributes for items and decoration views.

```
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)decorationIndexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes;

    if ([elementKind isEqualToString:AFCollectionViewFlowLayoutBackgroundDecoration])
    {
        if ([insertedSectionSet containsObject:@(decorationIndexPath.section)])
        {
            layoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:elementKind atIndexPath:decorationIndexPath];
            layoutAttributes.alpha = 0.0f;
            layoutAttributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-CGRectGetWidth(layoutAttributes.frame), 0, 0);
        }
    }

    return layoutAttributes;
}

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes;

    if ([insertedSectionSet containsObject:@(itemIndexPath.section)])
    {
        layoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
        layoutAttributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation([self collectionViewContentSize].width, 0, 0);
    }

    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

I'm returning `nil` from these methods otherwise because `nil` is the default value.

This has the added benefit of having nicer rotation animations, as well.